# Spring Data Rest PersistentEntityResource Jackson serialization goes into StackOveflowError

Tags: java, jackson, spring-data-rest

I'm using the latest snapshot spring-data-rest-webmvc:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.
When Jackson tries to serialize PersistentEntityResource to JSON, it goes into an infinite loop on the "persistentEntity" property. I understand the property is supposed to be ignored, but it's not.

```
public class PersistentEntityResource<T> extends Resource<T> {
    @JsonIgnore private final PersistentEntity<?, ?> entity;
    ...
    public PersistentEntity<?, ?> getPersistentEntity() {
        return entity;
    }
}
```

Maybe Jackson sees the getter that doesn't match the name of the field and decides to serialize? Or do I have some configuration wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by making sure that I don't have another bean in the spring context called "objectMapper". It was a default Jackson ObjectMapper that was overwriting the custom one configured in RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an error reported here:

https://jira.springsource.org/browse/DATAREST-117?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel

Comment: You pointed me in the right direction. There seems to be an issue with @JsonIgnore, but there real issue is that I was using the default ObjectMapper not the one configured in RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration. So it's the combination of the two issues.